# How to remove the fatal error when fetching an assoc array

Tags: php, mysqli

I am receiving a fatal error in my php/mysqli code which states that on line 46:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::fetch_assoc() in ...
```

I just want to know how can I remove this fatal error?

The line of code it is pointing at is here:

```
$row = $stmt->fetch_assoc();
```

ORIGINAL CODE:

```
$query = "SELECT Username, Email FROM User WHERE User = ?";
// prepare query
$stmt=$mysqli->prepare($query);
// You only need to call bind_param once
$stmt->bind_param("s",$user);
// execute query
$stmt->execute(); 
// get result and assign variables (prefix with db)
$stmt->bind_result($dbUser, $dbEmail);
//get number of rows
$stmt->store_result();
$numrows = $stmt->num_rows();                                      

if ($numrows == 1){

$row = $stmt->fetch_assoc();
$dbemail = $row['Email'];

}
```

UPDATED CODE:

```
$query = "SELECT Username, Email FROM User WHERE User = ?";
// prepare query
$stmt=$mysqli->prepare($query);
// You only need to call bind_param once
$stmt->bind_param("s",$user);
// execute query
$stmt->execute(); 
// get result and assign variables (prefix with db)
$stmt->bind_result($dbUser, $dbEmail);
//get number of rows
$stmt->store_result();
$numrows = $stmt->num_rows();                                      

if ($numrows == 1){    
  $row = $stmt->fetch_assoc();
  $dbemail = $row['Email'];    
}
```

Comment: your error means there is no method called fetch_assoc defined in mysqli_stmt class. method name must be different then what you have specified here in that class.

Comment: I beleive it should be $result = $stmt->execute(); $result->fetch_assoc();

Comment: Perhaps you should talk with your fellow classmates about this, because one of them seemed to have a similar issue a week ago on this same assignment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12101053/i-am-getting-errors-and-warnings-in-mysqli

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The variable $stmt is of type mysqli_stmt, not mysqli_result. The mysqli_stmt class doesn't have a method "fetch_assoc()" defined for it.

You can get a mysqli_result object from your mysqli_stmt object by calling its get_result() method. **For this you need the mysqlInd driver installed**!

```
$result = $stmt->get_result();
row = $result->fetch_assoc();
```

**If you don't have the driver installed** you can fetch your results like this:

```
$stmt->bind_result($dbUser, $dbEmail);
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    printf("%s %s\n", $dbUser, $dbEmail);
}
```

So your code should become:

```
$query = "SELECT Username, Email FROM User WHERE User = ?";
// prepare query
$stmt=$mysqli->prepare($query);
// You only need to call bind_param once
$stmt->bind_param("s",$user);
// execute query
$stmt->execute(); 
// bind variables to result
$stmt->bind_result($dbUser, $dbEmail);
//fetch the first result row, this pumps the result values in the bound variables
if($stmt->fetch()){
    echo 'result is ' . dbEmail;
}
```

Comment: `Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::get_result() in on line 42` It gives me this error pointing to `$result = $stmt->get_result();` if I include your code

Comment: Change that line to $result = $stmt->store_result(); and try again?

Comment: Haha, typical, if I change it to  `$result = $stmt->store_result();` I get this error: `Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object `.

Comment: change back to get_result and try to add this just after your $query=... line: $stmt = $mysqli->stmt_init();

Comment: It is giving me same error as error mentioned in first comment

Comment: I updated my answer, to use get_result you need the mysqlInd driver installed, if you don't have it, you need to use bind_result and fetch

Comment: I updated my code in the question, I have to use the bind_result() method, do you think the updated code would work now or do I still need to make a change?

Comment: Look closer at my code, do it exactly like that. $smtp->fetch() loads the result values in the variables you bound to the result using bind_result. You don't need to work with these methods' return values. It should work as I posted it

Comment: Also, you shouldn't update your code in the question, now future users with similar problems can't see the original code

Comment: Ok I will get the original code back and put updated code underneath

Comment: Ok that's much better, but try it first to see if it works :)

Comment: OK I don't know who editted the updated code in the question but if I use that one which includes the fetch_assoc(), then I get the fatal error, if I use the fetch(), then I get no errors at all. So am I better off using the fetch() rather than the fetch_assoc()? What is the difference between the two?

Comment: You need to use fetch(), fetch works with the bound variables. fetch_assoc won't work in your case. The code was reverted to the original post by an admin, on my advice.

Answer (score 0):

Change,

```
$stmt->store_result();
```

to

```
$result = $stmt->store_result();
```

And

Change,

```
$row = $stmt->fetch_assoc();
```

to

```
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
```

Comment: store_result returns a bool value, not a result object.

Answer (score 0):

You have missed this step

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id, label FROM test WHERE id = 1");
$stmt->execute();
$res = $stmt->get_result(); // you have missed this step
$row = $res->fetch_assoc();
```

Comment: I am discussing this with Jeroes Moon, if I do this then it gives me a fatal error stating `Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::get_result()`

Comment: You are not showing the mysqli line, are you creating it using new keyword.

Comment: The line it is pointing to is this:` $result = $stmt->get_result();`, I just changed your $res to $result

Answer (score 0):

I realized that this code was provided as an answer somewhere on stackoverflow:

```
//get number of rows
$stmt->store_result();
$numrows = $stmt->num_rows();
```

I tried it to get the number of rows but realized that i didnt need the line `$stmt->store_result();`, and it didn't get me my number. I used this:

```
$result      = $stmt->get_result();
$num_of_rows = $result->num_rows;
......
$row         = $result->fetch_assoc();
$sample      = $row['sample'];
```

Answer (score 0):

It's best to use mysqlnd as Asciiom pointed out. But if you're in a weird situation where you are not allowed to install mysqlnd, it is still possible to get your data into an associative array without it. Try using the code in this answer
[Mysqli - Bind results to an Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24363755/mysqli-bind-results-to-an-array)