# PHP mysqli script error 500

Tags: php, database, mysqli

i have this script to connect my DB and i get error 500 when using it.

I tried to track where the error is and i think its at this line: `while ($row = $stmt->fetch_assoc())`

But i looked over examples and its the same is mine.

Here is my code thanks for helping:

```
<?php


    $mysqli = new mysqli(*MY DB DETAILS*);

    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
   }

     $sql = "SELECT * FROM comments WHERE workout_name =? AND user =?"; 

    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql) or trigger_error($mysqli->error."[$sql]");

    $stmt->bind_param('ss', $workout_name, $user);

    $workout_name = $_GET['workout_name'];
    $user = $_GET['user'];

    $stmt->execute();

    if ($stmt) 
    {
        while ($row = $stmt->fetch_assoc()) 
    {
        $response["name"] = $row["workout_name"];
        echo json_encode($response);
    }

            $response["success"] = 1;

            // echoing JSON response
            echo json_encode($response);
    }

    else
    {
        $response["success"] = 2;

            // echoing JSON response
         echo json_encode($response);
    }

?>
```

**UPDATE:**

I had to change `$row = $stmt->fetch_assoc()`

as described here:

[How to remove the fatal error when fetching an assoc array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12178373/how-to-remove-the-fatal-error-when-fetching-an-assoc-array)

Comment: Why haven't you enabled error display? I don't see initializing $response variable as array.

Comment: Look in your webserver error logs to find the meaning of the error 500.

Comment: How do i check the webserver error log?

Comment: That depends on the webserver software you're using, and it's a little out of scope here.  Talk to your system administrator.

Answer (score 0):

Before you do this line

```
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $workout_name, $user);
```

You have to set  $workout_name and $user to contain a value. 
eg

```
$workout_name = 'pumping iron';
$user = 'Arnold Schwarzenegger';
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $workout_name, $user);
```

In your case as you have not even created these variables yet. I assume you are getting the 500 error because the mysqli code goes BANG trying to find NON-EXISTANT variables to load data from.

Comment: @Crontab ??? You corrected my spelling of Arnies family name, which is quite irrelevant to the answer, but left a misspelling of `veriables and a missing full stop between yet and I. Are you for real??

Comment: That's what I get for leaving my machine unlocked for 5 minutes at work.  Apologies.

Comment: @Crontab No problem it made me laugh or rather LOL.