# workaround for mysqlnd missing driver

Tags: php, mysql

My hosting provider has PHP 5.3 without mysqlnd installed, and thus it returns an error when I call mysqli_stmt_get_result()

is there any workaround to achieve the same functionality without having to install mysqlnd?

I don't want to change 100's of functions, if there's an easier method, any help will be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went through a lot of trouble on a server where mysqlnd wasn't available, and had a lot of headaches.

If you don't have mysqlnd installed/loaded whatever, you will get an undefined reference when trying to call `mysqli_stmt_get_result()`.

I wrote my own `mysqli_stmt_get_result()` and a `mysqli_result_fetch_array()` to go with it.

```
<?php
class iimysqli_result
{
    public $stmt, $nCols;
}    

function iimysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt)
{
    /**    EXPLANATION:
     * We are creating a fake "result" structure to enable us to have
     * source-level equivalent syntax to a query executed via
     * mysqli_query().
     *
     *    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, "");
     *    mysqli_bind_param($stmt, "types", ...);
     *
     *    $param1 = 0;
     *    $param2 = 'foo';
     *    $param3 = 'bar';
     *    mysqli_execute($stmt);
     *    $result _mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
     *        [ $arr = _mysqli_result_fetch_array($result);
     *            || $assoc = _mysqli_result_fetch_assoc($result); ]
     *    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
     *    mysqli_close($conn);
     *
     * At the source level, there is no difference between this and mysqlnd.
     **/
    $metadata = mysqli_stmt_result_metadata($stmt);
    $ret = new iimysqli_result;
    if (!$ret) return NULL;

    $ret->nCols = mysqli_num_fields($metadata);
    $ret->stmt = $stmt;

    mysqli_free_result($metadata);
    return $ret;
}

function iimysqli_result_fetch_array(&$result)
{
    $ret = array();
    $code = "return mysqli_stmt_bind_result(\$result->stmt ";

    for ($i=0; $i<$result->nCols; $i++)
    {
        $ret[$i] = NULL;
        $code .= ", \$ret['" .$i ."']";
    };

    $code .= ");";
    if (!eval($code)) { return NULL; };

    // This should advance the "$stmt" cursor.
    if (!mysqli_stmt_fetch($result->stmt)) { return NULL; };

    // Return the array we built.
    return $ret;
}
?>
```

Comment: it works perfectly, but only one drawback, it returns non-keyed array (i.e. no assoc)

Answer (score 0):

This related question has another workaround to get data without installing mysqlnd. It puts the data into an associative array.

[Mysqli - Bind results to an Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24363755/mysqli-bind-results-to-an-array)

Answer (score 0):

The solution from Daan is very nice! For this, i have to say thank you!

The point is, that i had, based on this, developed a class which works with mysqlnd, when it's there and Daan's alternative when it's missing.

I have built in fetchAssoc, fetchAllAssoc/Array, num_rows as methods. It's still in development and part of youphptube. This maybe also helps Ehab (whish for fetchAssoc).

https://github.com/DanielnetoDotCom/YouPHPTube/blob/master/objects/mysql_dal.php

Usage:

```
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ?";
    $res = sqlDAL::readSql($sql,"i",array($users_id)); 
    $fullData = sqlDAL::fetchAllAssoc($res);
    // $data = sqlDAL::fetchAssoc($res); $data2 = sqlDAL::fetchAssoc($res); // or like this
    // $countedRows = sqlDAL::num_rows($res); // or like this
    sqlDAL::close($res);
```

I would made this as a sub-post to Daan's answer, but my reputation is too small.