# PHP: Errors in my code, mainly mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter mysqli_result, object given

Tags: php, mysqli

Can somebody help me fix my code?
I am trying to access a database of password hashes and use them to validate the user login, but I get a couple of errors.

```
<?php
$servername="localhost";
$username = "*****";
$password = "*******";
$dbname = "*****";
$conn = new mysqli($servername,$username,$password,$dbname);
if($conn->connect_error){
    die("Connection to database failed: ".$conn->connect_error);
}
$uname=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['entered_username']);
$pw=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['entered_password']);

$stmt=$conn->prepare("SELECT username,password,password_hash FROM users WHERE username=?");
$stmt->bind_param('s',$uname);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
$stmt->bind_result($result);
$stmt->fetch();

if(!$stmt){
echo $conn->connect_error();}
if($stmt){
echo 'Connection successful';}

$found=FALSE;

while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($stmt))
{
    if($password_verify($pw,$row['password_hash'])) {
        $found=TRUE;
    }
}


if($found){
    echo "You have successfully logged in as ".$uname."!";
}
else {
    echo "Login as ".$uname." failed!";
}
$stmt->close();
$conn->close();
?>
```

What I get as output:

> Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_result(): Number of bind variables doesn't
>   match number of fields in prepared statement in
>   /****/login3.php on line 27
>   
> Connection successful
>   
> Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result,
>   object given in /****/login3.php on line 37
>   
> Login as admin failed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks guys! It works now! I changed the bind_result statement and got rid of the fetch statement. Apparently, [$stmt is of type mysqli_stmt, not mysqli_result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12178373/how-to-remove-the-fatal-error-when-fetching-an-assoc-array) and the mysqli_stmt class doesn't have a method fetch_assoc() defined for it.

```
$stmt=$conn->prepare("SELECT username,password_hash FROM users WHERE username=?");
$stmt->bind_param('s',$uname);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
$stmt->bind_result($user,$password_hash);

$found=FALSE;

while($stmt->fetch())
{
    if(password_verify($pw,$password_hash)) {
        $found=TRUE;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing it up. Try with -

```
$stmt=$conn->prepare("SELECT username,password,password_hash FROM users WHERE username=?");
$stmt->bind_param('s',$uname);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
$stmt->bind_result($result);


if(!$stmt){
echo $conn->connect_error();}
if($stmt){
echo 'Connection successful';}

$found=FALSE;

while($row=$stmt->fetch_assoc();)
{
    if($password_verify($pw,$row['password_hash'])) {
        $found=TRUE;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to bind the columns, as  it has to match number of fields requiring:

check this out:

```
<?php
$servername="localhost";
$username = "*****";
$password = "*******";
$dbname = "*****";
$conn = new mysqli($servername,$username,$password,$dbname);
if($conn->connect_error){
    die("Connection to database failed: ".$conn->connect_error);
}
$uname=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['entered_username']);
$pw=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['entered_password']);

$stmt=$conn->prepare("SELECT username,password,password_hash FROM users WHERE username=?");
$stmt->bind_param('s',$uname);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
$stmt->bind_result($username,$password,$password_hash);
$stmt->fetch();

if(!$stmt){
echo $conn->connect_error();}
if($stmt){
echo 'Connection successful';}

$found=FALSE;

while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($stmt))
{
    if($password_verify($pw,$password_hash)) {
        $found=TRUE;
    }
}


if($found){
    echo "You have successfully logged in as ".$uname."!";
}
else {
    echo "Login as ".$uname." failed!";
}
$stmt->close();
$conn->close();
?>
```