# Using a prepared statement in php & mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am using prepared statements for the first time. And i cannot get the select to work.
For some reason, it returns all the records but i cannot get them into variables. I know it returns all the records because if i add `echo '1';` to the loop it echo's 1 for each record.

Any assistance would be great. The code is below:

```
function builditems($quote_id){
        if ($stmt = $this->link->prepare("SELECT * FROM `0_quotes_items`  WHERE `quote_id` = ?")) {
            // Bind a variable to the parameter as a string.
            $stmt->bind_param("i", $quote_id);
            // Execute the statement.
            $stmt->execute();
              while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
                  echo $row['id'];
                }


            // Close the prepared statement.
            $stmt->close();         
            }
        }
```

**UPDATE:**
in the error log, i see the following error after adding the `while ($row = $stmt->fetch_assoc()) {` like suggested:

`PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::fetch_assoc()`

I found a link that the same issue was had, but i do not understand how to implement the fix.
Any assistance would be great, with regards to a example.

[How to remove the fatal error when fetching an assoc array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12178373/how-to-remove-the-fatal-error-when-fetching-an-assoc-array)

Answer (score 1):

The PHP MySQLi `fetch` method does not access query data using brackets notation: `$row['id']`.

So I see two options to remedy: first find this line:

```
while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
```

...and modify it to, **either**, first add the `bind_result` method, and then access the data a bit differently:

```
$stmt->bind_result($id, $other, $whatnot); // assuming 3 columns retrieved in the query
while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
  echo "$id $other $whatnot<br>";
}
```

...**or**, first access the *result* object's `fetch_assoc` method and use `fetch_assoc` instead of `fetch`:

```
$result = $stmt->get_result();
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
```

Now you can use table column names as keys to access query data in your loop: `$row['id']`.

---

PHP MySQLi method [`fetch`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php) requires you to use `bind_result`. Doing this allows you to call your data by the variable names you've bound it to.

To use the field name as the result array index, such as: `$row['id']`, you need to use the PHP MySQLi [`fetch_assoc`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) method. And to use `fetch_assoc` you need to first get the *result* object in order to access the `fetch_assoc` method.

Comment: I changed it and when i reloaded the form. The entire form was thrown out, All the styling was lost. As soon as i remove  the _assoc the problem goes away.
Why would the form crash like that?

Comment: The code you posted looks fine. I need to see what  calls builditems to investigate. I suggest opening another question sin e this one is solved.

Comment: its just a function that is calling at the moment. I intent to return the values in a table. But i cannot get the values from the database.

Comment: What are the column names in the table? Is one of them named *id*, hence `$row['id']`?

Comment: Yes one of them is id, it is the auto inc value.
I am just trying to get the first out. Before moving to the rest.

Comment: Ah, I see the problem. Your update with link to your question solved it for me. I updated my response, and I have a working example on my end.

Comment: I have added the last option you mentioned. the `$result = $stmt->get_result();` and i get the following error when the page loads now. `PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::get_result()`;

Comment: To debug change your `execute` line to `$stmt->execute() or die($this->link->error);` and report what you get.