# Using fetch_assoc on prepared statements

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I'm currently working on a login script, and I got this code:

```
$selectUser = $db->prepare("SELECT `id`,`password`,`salt` FROM `users` WHERE `username`=?");
$selectUser->bind_param('s', $username);
$selectUser->execute();

if ($selectUser->num_rows() < 0)
    echo "no_user";
else
{
    $user = $selectUser->fetch_assoc();
    echo $user['id'];
}
```

Here's the error I get:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method
>   mysqli_stmt::fetch_assoc()

I tried all sorts of variations, like:

```
$result = $selectUser->execute();
$user = $result->fetch_assoc();
```

and more... nothing worked.

Comment: you need the mysqlInd driver

Comment: and if I can't install it, what other options do I have to achieve the same result?

Comment: fetch like this while ($result->fetch()) {
   ........
}

Comment: Please post this as an answer

Comment: If you don't have the mysqlInd driver, this solution worked a treat for me: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28622062/1617737

Answer (score 19):

That's because `fetch_assoc` is not part of a `mysqli_stmt` object. `fetch_assoc` belongs to the `mysqli_result` class. You can use `mysqli_stmt::get_result` to first get a result object and then call `fetch_assoc`:

```
$selectUser = $db->prepare("SELECT `id`,`password`,`salt` FROM `users` WHERE `username`=?");
$selectUser->bind_param('s', $username);
$selectUser->execute();
$result = $selectUser->get_result();
$assoc = $result->fetch_assoc();
```

Alternatively, you can use `bind_result` to bind the query's columns to variables and use `fetch()` instead:

```
$selectUser = $db->prepare("SELECT `id`,`password`,`salt` FROM `users` WHERE `username`=?");
$selectUser->bind_param('s', $username);
$selectUser->bind_result($id, $password, $salt);
$selectUser->execute();
while($selectUser->fetch())
{
    //$id, $password and $salt contain the values you're looking for
}
```

Comment: If you get a `Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::get_result` error look into this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8343970/2056125

Answer (score 0):

1)   you need the mysqlInd driver.

The variable `$db` is of type mysqli_stmt, not mysqli_result. The mysqli_stmt class doesn't have a method **fetch_assoc()** defined for it.

You can get a `mysqli_result` object from your `mysqli_stmt` object by calling its **get_result()** method. For this you need the mysqlInd driver installed!

Alternative try this

```
    $selectUser = $db->prepare("SELECT `id`,`password`,`salt` FROM `users` WHERE `username`=?");
    $selectUser->bind_param('s', $username);

     $selectUser->execute();
    $selectUser->bind_result($id, $password,$salt);

    while ($selectUser->fetch()) {
        printf("%s %s %s\n", $id, $password,$salt);
    }
```

[for more info about this Reference link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12178373/how-to-remove-the-fatal-error-when-fetching-an-assoc-array)

Answer (score 0):

Now talk of alternatives.

**PDO**, unlike mysqli, never have a problem like this. It can fetch you an array out of a prepared statement without the need of installing any additional modules.

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT `id`,`password`,`salt` FROM `users` WHERE `username`=?");
$stmt->execute([$username]);
$user = $stmt->fetch();

if (!$user) {
    echo "no_user";
} else {
    echo $user['id'];
}
```

See, it works exactly the way you would expect and require two times less code to write. Not to mention [other wonderful features](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#fetchall).