# FIndng the exact value in a table in PHP Issue

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have this code.

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM UserData WHERE username = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('s',$username);
//$username = $_POST["username"];
$username ="netsgets";
$stmt->execute();
$row = $stmt->fetch_assoc();
$stmt->store_result(); 
var_dump($stmt['likedFour']);
echo "hi";
```

This should check the value of `likeFour` in the row chosen and echo it in `var_dump()`. For some reason it is stopping at the `$row` part and doesn't echo "hi". Please help.

Comment: I added it. Oops.

Comment: it seems that [`fetch_assoc`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) returns the array with the result. Right now you are getting the data and discarding it

Comment: @litelite how would i fix this.

Comment: Just like your previous question, you're still missing the `$` in `var_dump(stmt['likedFour']);`. It should be `var_dump($stmt['likedFour']);`, or `var_dump($row['likedFour']);`

Comment: thatwas a typo i already changed it

Comment: Check your server error logs. If it's not showing `hi`, then it's throwing an error which will give you more information.

Comment: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::fetch_assoc()

Comment: Thats the error.

Comment: Open mysqli manual. Everything is explained there.

Comment: http://docs.php.net/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php

Comment: Actual duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12178373/how-to-remove-the-fatal-error-when-fetching-an-assoc-array

Comment: thats not me...

Comment: You can't call `fetch_assoc()` on a statement. You need to use [`mysqli_stmt::get_result()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php)  *first*. See the manual for that. Note the `mysqlnd` driver requirement.